# How can I set a specific frame on hover

Tags: animation, canvas, createjs

I'm trying to jump to a specifik position (frame) when the mouse is over my ad. I have tried:

```
var element = document.getElementById('animation_container');
element.addEventListener('mouseover', element, function() {
  createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", stage);
  createjs.Tween.setPosition(502);
});
element.addEventListener('mouseleave', element, function() {
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
});
```

The above is not working. The animation is stopped but I'm unable to change the actual frame of on the canvas.

Perhaps I need to restart the animation using `fnStartAnimation()` and in this function state the starting position of the animation? Would appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are removing the "tick" even from the stage before you set the position. If there is no stage update going, you won't see any changes to the canvas. You need to update the stage one more time after you do the changes.

Firstly you need to return the tween instance of your tween animation, in order to apply the function directly to it:

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(target);
```

Then, you can try this as the listener function:

```
createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", stage);
tween.setPosition(502);
stage.update();
```

Or, you can also try to pause the Tween without ever removing the stage tick, with:

```
tween.setPaused(true);
```

By the way, as far as I know, event listeners will have the listener function as the second parameter, and not the target element.

Comment: The thing is that I only would like to go to a specifik frame in the timeline. I assume this could be done through gotoAndPlay() or similar?

Comment: In this case, you would want to use `gotoAndStop(frame)`, in order to also stop the animation after setting the frame, and not just keep playing it. But those 2 are functions that are used for MovieClip types of objects, and not Tweens, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Yes this might be the case. I have not created the original code and in fact I don't think they use the Tween library at all.